# Is there any way to capture the android 'GO' button or iPhone 'GO' button in jquery?

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, html, form-submit

I am building a mobile website, In this a form is there but no submit button. So when the user types something in the input field and clicks on Android or iPhone GO button it should submit the form. I'm using HTML and jQuery for this.

How can I capture this GO event in jQuery? I want it to be done this way it self.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a submit-button and set its `opacity` to `0`.

I used this for html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="input" />
    <input type="submit" style="opacity:0;" />
</form>
```

And this to `alert()` the value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        alert($("[name=input]").val());
    });
});
```

You just need to handle the submit-Event of the form, this works great with jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

You can use webview to load html file in android/iphone devices.

Check the below,

1. Add index.html under assets folder in android. and add the following in mainActivity class. here named StackOverFlowActivity

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Handler;
   import android.webkit.WebView;

   public class StackOverFlowActivity extends Activity {

   private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
       view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
       view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
   }

   final class MyJavaScriptInterface
   {
       public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
           {             
               mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                   {
                       public void run()
                           {
                               String h="Hi";
                               webview.loadUrl("javascript:result(\""+h+"\")");
                           }
                   });
           }
   }
   ```

   }
2. index.html

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function clickhere()()
   {
      Android.ProcessJavaScript("result",null); 
   }

   function result(res) 
   {

       alert(res);       
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <input type="button" id="clickme" onclick="clickhere()" value="GO"></input>
    </body>
    </html>
   ```

Comment: That's a pretty cool way, but he is developing a mobile website, not an app ;-)

Comment: I tried to flag this as 'not an answer' since it is not related to the question that was asked, even though it would be helpful on another question. This flag was unfortunately disputed by a reviewer, so I am downvoting in the hope that it might be deleted by the poster. Apologies!